# Creating an error message

Tags: macros, conditionals

Is there a way to create my own error message that is given if the main font size isn't set to 11pt and then the compilation of the document begin stopped?

---

### Update

I'm trying to write a package, and I use:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%or scrbook or scrartcl

\usepackage{classicthesis}
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just set the font size, since you want to stop the compilation if it is something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're writing a package, say `foo.sty` then

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \if\@ptsize1\else
    \PackageError{foo}
      {Illegal font size option detected.\MessageBreak
       This is a fatal error, I'll stop the run}
      {You have specified a point size different from\MessageBreak
       the unique size this package supports, which is 11pt.\MessageBreak
       Correct your input file}
    \expandafter\@@end
  \fi}
```

will do.

Comment: if could help, I have updated my question. Another thing, I haven't understand why I need to ensure that the 11pt option is correctly passed to the main class. And exactly where I must put that code. Thanks.

Comment: @FormlessCloud The code should be in your package. I've removed the references to a class.

Comment: Sure, but I was referring to the deleted code: `\LoadClassWithOptions...`

Comment: @FormlessCloud Since you're *not* writing a class, that code means nothing.

Comment: Ok thanks, it was only to know something more.

Comment: Where is `PackageError` documented?

Comment: @buhtz You find it in the “LaTeX Companion” and in `texdoc source2e.pdf`

Comment: @buhtz ...and in the document "LaTeX2e for class and package writers": https://www.ctan.org/pkg/clsguide

Answer (score 6):

If you're using one of the standard document classes (`article`, `book` or `report`), the macro `\@ptsize` contains `1` if you're using `11pt`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newcommand{\@ptsizetest}{1}% Equivalent to 11pt for a document class option.
  \ifx\@ptsizetest\@ptsize\relax\else
    \@latex@error
      {You need to use 11pt font size}% Error message
      {Add this as a document class option [11pt]}% Help text
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test document
\end{document}​
```

This creates the error

> LaTeX Error: You need to use 11pt font size.

If you're using other packages that define the font size, some more work is required.